# what is this syntax referring to?

Tags: java, android

I am reading some code snippets in a project and I found some functions with this signature. Can someone explain to me what's the part before the return type represents?

```
 private <T extends SessionRequest> void continueSession(T request, Action action)
```

Comment: is a generic method with constraints....

Comment: The T is a wildcard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_(Java)

Comment: `T` must be of a type extending from `SessionRequest` to be accepted as a parameter of the method.

Comment: @px06 so private void continueSession(SessionRequest request,Action action) is the same?

Comment: @libathos Not quite, because that would mean that the `request` parameter **must** only be of type `SessionRequest`, if `T extends SessionRequest` then `request` can be of anything that inherits from `SessionRequest` like: `class MyClass extends SessionRequest {...}`

Comment: @px06 great I got it thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a generic method with constraints....
imagine following

```
private void continueSession(T request){}
```

then your people can do something like:

```
continueSession("Hi");
```

or

```
continueSession(1000);
```

so you need to be able at compiling time to constrains what is the method taking as parameter....

now if you do

```
private  <T extends Number> void continueSession(T request){}
```

then trying to call

```
continueSession("Hi");
```

will never compile since string is not a child class of `Number` so to answer your question this:

```
 private <T extends SessionRequest> void continueSession(T request, Action action)
```

is allowing only objects that are either

- child class of **SessionRequest**
  or
- implements the interface **SessionRequest**